# World background texture not showing in render

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, world

I just started out using Blender Render. I wanted to create a starry background for my world and did so, and it appears nice and fine in the preview for both texture and world. Yet when I render the image, my objects appear fine but the background texture will not appear. I looked at several other similar posts online but all seem to refer to older versions of Blender, unless I'm missing something. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, knowing a bit more (settings, screenshots, image) about how you did set up the world would help to spot why what you expect is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Blender Render (internal), and for a flat repeating background (not a wrap-around 360 background) try the following things:

- Add a world texture (if you haven't already)

  - Properties > Texture panel
  - Click the "World" tab (it's one of the three little buttons at top of texture panel)
  - Add texture
  - Type: Image or Movie
  - Image > (open image file here)

[image]

- Check influence

  - Under the "Influence" section of the world texture I had to check "Horizon" before the world background would render
- Check mapping

  - Mapping > Size
  - Increase X, Y, and Z values to make background (starfield, in this case) smaller and repeat more often

[image]

- Sky shading (instead of transparent)

  - Properties > Render > Shading > Alpha: [Sky]

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the last point about shading that fixed it. Much appreciated.